# Google Drive returning empty files array (php)

Tags: php, google-api, google-drive-api

I am trying to open a specific folder within my Google Drive, but I am getting a empty "Files" array in return on the majority of my requests.

I am just using the example snippet from Google:

```
  try {
    $client = getClient();
    $driveService = new Drive($client);
    $files = array();
    $pageToken = null;
    do {
        $response = $driveService->files->listFiles(array([
            'q' => "'$folder' in parents",
            'spaces' => 'drive',
            'pageToken' => $pageToken,
            'fields' => 'nextPageToken, files(id, name)',
        ]));
        foreach ($response->files as $file) {
            printf("Found file: %s (%s)\n", $file->name, $file->id);
        }
        array_push($files, $response->files);

        $pageToken = $response->pageToken;
    } while ($pageToken != null);
    return $files;
} catch(Exception $e) {
   echo "Error Message: ".$e;
}
```

When I put the same query parameters in the API Explorer though, everything returns the correct contents. I can't seem to find the difference between the API explorer and my app's query.

Answer (score 1):

#### Modification points:

- From `When I put the same query parameters in the API Explorer though, everything returns the correct contents.`, I guessed that you want to retrieve the file list with the search query of `"'$folder' in parents"`. In this case, I thought that `array([,,,])` is required to be modified to `array(,,,)`.
- `array_push($files, $response->files);` might be `$files = array_merge($files, $response->files);`.
- `$pageToken = $response->pageToken;` should be `$pageToken = $response->nextPageToken;`.

When these points are reflected in your script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

##### From:

```
do {
    $response = $driveService->files->listFiles(array([
        'q' => "'$folder' in parents",
        'spaces' => 'drive',
        'pageToken' => $pageToken,
        'fields' => 'nextPageToken, files(id, name)',
    ]));
    foreach ($response->files as $file) {
        printf("Found file: %s (%s)\n", $file->name, $file->id);
    }
    array_push($files, $response->files);

    $pageToken = $response->pageToken;
} while ($pageToken != null);
```

##### To:

```
do {
    $response = $driveService->files->listFiles(array(
        'q' => "'$folder' in parents and trashed=false",
        'spaces' => 'drive',
        'pageToken' => $pageToken,
        'fields' => 'nextPageToken, files(id, name)',
        'pageSize' => 1000,
    ));
    foreach ($response->files as $file) {
        printf("Found file: %s (%s)\n", $file->name, $file->id);
    }
    $files = array_merge($files, $response->files);
    $pageToken = $response->nextPageToken;
} while ($pageToken != null);
```

#### Note:

- This modification supposes that your `$client = getClient();` can be used for retrieving the file list from `$folder`. Please be careful about this.
- If you want to retrieve the file list from the shared Drive, please test the following modification.

  ```
    do {
        $response = $driveService->files->listFiles(array(
            'q' => "'$folder' in parents and trashed=false",
            'spaces' => 'drive',
            'pageToken' => $pageToken,
            'fields' => 'nextPageToken, files(id, name)',
            'pageSize' => 1000,
            'includeItemsFromAllDrives' => true,
            'supportsAllDrives' => true,
            'corpora' => "allDrives",
        ));
        foreach ($response->files as $file) {
            printf("Found file: %s (%s)\n", $file->name, $file->id);
        }
        $files = array_merge($files, $response->files);
        $pageToken = $response->nextPageToken;
    } while ($pageToken != null);
  ```

#### Note:

- When I tested the above script, I confirmed that the file list can be obtained. If the same situation occurred when you tested the above modification, can you provide detailed information about `When I put the same query parameters in the API Explorer though, everything returns the correct contents.`? By this, I would like to confirm it.

#### Reference:

- [Files: list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list)